# How can I change typescript settings when installed globally on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: typescript, ubuntu

I have installed typescript globally on Ubuntu 22.04 using the command `npm install -g typescript`. Now I want to change some of the settings. I have tried `tsc --target es2015` on the command line but no effect. I have been trying to find a `tsconfig.json`-file, hoping to edit that, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tsconfig.json file must be located at the root of your website/app. Each website/app requires its own tsconfig file.

When you execute the 'npm build' command, Node.js will read the tsconfig.json file and search for the TypeScript package (regardless of whether it is installed locally or globally). It will then transpile your TypeScript code into JavaScript based on the settings specified in the tsconfig.json file

tsconfig.json can be like this

```
   {
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2015",
    "lib": [ "ES2015", "ES5", "dom", "ES2016", "ES6" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

Note that:

- the "lib" option is the syntax you are using in your ts code.
- the "target" option specifies the JavaScript version that you want to emit as the output.

Comment: It looks like I do not need a tsconfig.json-file in the root of my project when typescript is installed globally. It works just fine without that. I solved my problem by adding the `--target-option` to the compile-command like this: `tsc static/js/main.ts --target es2015 -w`

Comment: I recommend you using a config file to avoid having to worry about the configuration settings every time.

Comment: That may be a very good advice to consider. Thank you!